# Removing “Today”, “Yesterday”, “Last Week” from Outlook Web Access

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

How do I remove the "grouping" of my email into "Today", "Yesterday", "Last Week", etc. from Outlook Web Access. I know how to do this from the actual Outlook program, but I cannot figure out how to do it from the web interface.

[image: screenshot]

I just want emails list, one after another...These are NOT conversations. :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an obsolete user interface and rebranded product.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `view` tab in outlook mail. Click on `Arrange by`, then uncheck `Show in Groups`.

Comment: This is for OWA. There is no "arrange by" under the view tab?

Comment: @DaveZ : In my case if I access my `OWA` mail directly from web, I will not see mails arrange by `Yesterday`, `Last week` etc ..But if I configure my `OWA` mail with `MS Outlook`, then this arrangement show and I can remove that arrangement from `view` tab.

Comment: This was already unticked on my mailbox, but not in search for some reason.
After ticking it in mailbox and then untick it again it is no longer in search ether..
Might add that this office workstation has been upgraded 3times so would make sense that things are broken along the way.

Answer (score 1):

As of 3/11/2020 as related to OWA.

Go to settings on the top right corner (gear icon).  Click view all outlook settings (bottom right pane).  Mail tab (default) and scroll to the bottom.  Select Don't show date headers in the message list.

As always with Microsoft subject to change without notice.

Answer (score 1):

Your OWA should be the same as the Outlook client in the Office suite.  Go to the View tab and find the Arrangement box.  Click the Scroll Down arrow to see all of the choices in the Arrangement box.  One of the choices should be Show in Groups.  Uncheck that option and the groupings of Today, Yesterday, Last Week, etc... will go away.